# How do you design a Pricing Integration for Hybris with SAP ERP for B2B application

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

If there is a pricing module in ERP which calculates the price on real time basis for each user, is there any way we get it without performance tradeoff?

Comment: I would say just implement some cache to avoid to much calls against your ERP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can maintain Cache to avoid multiple calls to ERP system.

Here is a sample code which you can try to implement cache --

**CustomCache.java**

```
public class CustomCache
{

    @Resource(name = customCacheRegion)
    protected CacheAccess customCacheAccess;

    //Fetch result from cache
    public ResultData readCachedData(final B2BUnitModel customer, final Date date)
    {
       return (ResultData) customCacheAccess.get(createCacheKey(customer, date));
    }

    //Update result to cache
    public void cacheResult(final B2BUnitModel customer, final Date date,
        final ResultData resultData)
    {

       try
       {
          customCacheAccess.put(createCacheKey(customer, date), resultData);

       }
       catch (final SAPHybrisCacheException e)
       {
        //error
       }
    }

    protected CustomCacheKey createCacheKey(final B2BUnitModel customer, final Date date)
    {
       return new CustomCacheKey(customer, date);
    }

}
```

---

**Cache KEY -**

```
  public class CustomCacheKey extends AbstractCacheKey
  {
        private final B2BUnitModel customer;

        private final Date date; 

        @Override
        public int hashCode()
        {
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = super.hashCode();
            result = prime * result + ((customer == null) ? 0 : customer.hashCode());
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(final Object obj)
        {
           if (obj == null)
           {
              return false;
           }

           if (!super.equals(obj))
           {
               return false;
           }

           final CustomCacheKey customCacheKey = (CustomCacheKey ) obj;
           if (customer == null)
           {
                if (customCacheKey.customer != null)
                {
                   return false;
                }
           }
           else if (!customer.equals(customCacheKey.customer))
           {
               return false;
           }

           if (date == null)
           {
               if (customCacheKey.date != null)
               {
                 return false;
           }
        }
        else if (!DateUtils.isSameDay(date, customCacheKey.date))
        {
           return false;
        }

        return true;
     }
}
```

---

***-spring.xml --**

```
 <bean id="customCacheRegion" parent="sapCoreCacheRegion">
    <constructor-arg name="name"
        value="customCacheRegion" />
    <constructor-arg name="maxEntries" value="10000" />
    <constructor-arg name="evictionPolicy" value="FIFO" />
    <constructor-arg name="statsEnabled" value="true" />
    <constructor-arg name="exclusiveComputation" value="false" />
    <constructor-arg name="ttlSeconds" value="300" />
</bean>

<bean
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="cacheRegionsList" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="add" />
    <property name="arguments">
        <ref bean="customCacheRegion" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

So Cache is a kind of map where you can define key value pair and fetch the cached value from the key itself.

Finally in your service layer, before calling ERP system, just check whether for particular customer (or some other condition in your case), data is available in cache or not. If it is available, just fetch it directly from cache otherwise call ERP system and update result to cache.

Comment: Thanks Shreshtt Bhatt. It really helps me.

Comment: @racha11 Would you please accept this answer if it works :)

Comment: what if the same user would change the entries/product, how would distinguish whether it should return the last cached prices or should call ERP?

Comment: @staticvoidmain We need to override equals() method to add all possible unique conditions so that if any of entries/product change, the equals() method simply return false and due to which key doesn't exist in the cache map and fall into ERP call.